# Tratar de mantener sesión con CURL logueandose en Twitter

Tags: php, curl, session, twitter, cookies

Estoy tratando de mantener la sesión entre diferentes peticiones con CURL logueandose en Twitter porque en algún punto se desloguea de Twitter

```
$sTarget = "https://twitter.com";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie". $usuario ."_tweet.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $usuario ."_tweet.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

  if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
           echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
        }

preg_match('<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)">', $html, $match);

$authenticity_token = $match[1];

if ($authenticity_token == "");
{       
preg_match('<input type="hidden" value="([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" name="authenticity_token">', $html, $matchprima);   
$authenticity_token = $matchprima[1];
}


$username = $usuario;
$password = "*******";

$sPost = "session[username_or_email]=$username&session[password]=$password&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=%2F&authenticity_token=$authenticity_token";

$sTarget = "https://twitter.com/sessions";  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sTarget);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
# display server response
$htmldos = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $htmldos, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
    parse_str($item, $cookie);
    $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
var_dump($cookies);


if(curl_errno($ch))
{
   echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

Cuando hago un var_dump de cookies para ver si los valores de las cookies son los mismos, en ["_twitter_sess"] veo que hay 2 strings diferentes en las 2 peticiones. No debería tener el mismo string aquí si la sesión se mantiene entre peticiones? Si es así, como lo logro?